# How to get particular array value in php?

Tags: php

I have the following `$qtips_messages` array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tips_title] => email_tips 
            [tips_message] => ex:xxxxx@xyz.com
            [tips_key] => key_email
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [tips_title] => website_tips 
            [tips_message] => ex:http://www.yahoo.co.in
            [tips_key] => key_website
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [tips_title] => zipcode_tips
            [tips_message] => ex:60612
            [tips_key] => key_zipcode
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tips_title] => phone_tips 
            [tips_message] => ex:1234567890
            [tips_key] => key_phone
        )
)
```

For example, I want to get the tips message for the tip_title 'email_tips'
I have tried with following code,

```
foreach($qtips_messages as $qtipsArray){
    foreach($qtipsArray as $qkey=>$qvalue){
        if($qtipsArray['tips_title'] == 'email_tips'){
            $emailtipsMessage = $qtipsArray['tips_message'];
        }
    }
}
```

When i ran the above code i did not get any value.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array  = array();
foreach($result AS $k =>$val)
   $array[$val['tips_key']]    = $val['tips_message'];
return $array;
```

Now the array $array have all the values for q-tips based on their keys...

Hope this will helps you...

Answer (score 2):

You only need one loop:

```
$message = null;
foreach ($array as $tips) {
    if ($tips['tips_title'] == 'email_tips') {
        $message = $tips['tips_message'];
        break;
    }
}
```

I'd probably go for something like this though:

```
$message = current(array_filter($array, function ($tip) { return $tip['tips_title'] == 'email_tips'; }));
echo $message['tips_message'];
```

Comment: Thanks,$array will be associative array ? still i did not get any value.

Comment: `$array` is your array, `$qtips_messages` I guess.

Comment: $message = null;
                foreach ($qtips_messages as $tips) {
                    if ($tips['tips_title'] == 'email_tips') {
                        $message = $tips['tips_message'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                echo $message; exit; sorry deceze, i did not get value

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/hxtMno7T I can only show you to way, you have to do the debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
$array  = array();  
foreach($qtips_messages AS $k =>$val):  
if($val['tips_title']=='email_tips')  
{  
  $array[$val['tips_key']] = $val['tips_message'];  
  print_r($array);  
  break;  
}  
endforeach;
```